# Virtual consoles (Alt + F1…F6) stopped working on Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Today I was using virtual console 1
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
to chroot to another filesystem.

When I came back to the X desktop, everything worked fine,
but when I tried to go back to virtual console 1 it just freezes until I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and I can move the mouse again.

Now this happens always;
I cannot switch to a virtual terminal anymore, not even after a reboot.

I am using Debian testing kernel 4.11.0-1 .

I don't even know if it is a package so I can try to reinstall it. 
How can I fix this?

System details:
Lenovo Thinkpad t430 
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-3210M 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000
lspci | grep -i vga: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
Memory: 8Gb

Comment: do you get a login prompt on VC1?   what do you mean by "freezes"?  just that VC (or the program you're running in it)? or the entire system?

Comment: No, not Even a login prompt on any vc. When i try to switch from the x server to a vc it only freezes the image, but nothing change.

Comment: ok, probably needs some system details - cpu, ram, kernel version, gpu brand/model, and gpu driver used at least.

Comment: I added more details of my system

Answer (score 1):

I think that answer will help you to know more about `TTYs` activated in your System, you have to do this command :

```
 systemctl list-units | grep getty
```

the result will give you active `TTYs`in your system, after this do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
folowed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, and retype the commande `systemctl list-units | grep getty` you should see the `TTY2` activated like whith an output like this :

```
getty@tty1.service     loaded active running   Getty on tty1
getty@tty2.service     loaded active running   Getty on tty2
```

if you dont have something like this that affirms that your `getty.service` is not activated and you should load it and enabl it.

Comment: yes, i can see tty2 nunning after pressing alt + f2  in systemctl, but still nothing happens.

Comment: so `TTYs` are here but the is a problem in switching.

Comment: what are printed in `/var/log/messages` and in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` you shoud have something like this : 
`[ 65780.326] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 65856.654] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this command:

```
systemctl restart getty-static.service
```

And a reboot.